llamaIndex, qdrant vector store - error: Node content not found in metadata. [javascript]
The stack:
a) qdrant store running in docker. It has alreadt a collection with point. Example of adding point to collection
 { id: 15, vector: documentEmbeddings[0], payload: { text: essay } }
b) LlamaIndex - javascript
Problem: when making the query I receive error during the last step "error: Node content not found in metadata"
Here's the code I run:
`let index = await VectorStoreIndex.fromVectorStore(vectorStore);
      const retriever = index.asRetriever();
      const nodesWithScore = await retriever.retrieve({ query: "query string" });
      const queryEngine = index.asQueryEngine({
        retriever,
    });`

I quess, the doument needs to have a metadata object but how do retrieve it from qdrant or how to add it ?
Any help much appreciated.
Expecting result from the query after getting the documents from Quadrant

Possibly related?
